# What do resonance pylons do?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

They're in the final mission for the 'Progeny' investigation, but they don't seem to do anything.  IIRC in XCOM 2 they were for timed mission events, but there is no timer here.  So what are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they give 2 shield each to Archons and Violet (the boss). Destroying them does remove the shields, but since there's only one Archon per encounter, that means it's not worth destroying them.